# how to know view drawing not yet?

Tags: android, android-viewtreeobserver

## fixed : 2018-02-09 , 13:00 (GMT+9)

> I change word `isDrawing` to `!isDrawn`

---

I want to use get width, height after `view drawn`

but I want to know `isDrawn` too

below code can earn `view drawn` status

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // after view drawn callback
    } 
});
```

actually I want to mechanism like below.

```
if(!isDrawn){
    ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            delete_this_listener()
            // after view drawn callback
            mustCallAfterDrawn()
        } 
    });
} else {
    mustCallAfterDrawn()
}
```

Comment: Use `addOnPreDrawListener` which is called just before view is drawn and use `ongloballayout` for drawing completion.

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' `onGlobalLayout` does not stand for "drawing completion". That's a callback which will be executed after `View#onLayout()`.

Comment: What use-case do you have? Why do you have to rely on such an `if` statement?

Comment: @azizbekian You are correct, what i meant was layout completion. I couldn't edit my comment :). We can use `view.Post(runnable)` for drawing completion.

Comment: thank you for your interst, but.... T_T... nobody know this isue ?? help me~~

Comment: @rochelade what issue? What use-case do you have? Why do you have to rely on such an `if` statement? Most possibly you are on a wrong way and should **not** ever need to have such an `if` statement

Comment: @azizbekian I want to call `mustCallAfterDrawn()` method after drawn once. but if it is not on onCreate or something - for example, in callback function? so I don't have idea to know isDrawing or not... do I need to make a boolean flag and set true when that view drawn? I don't want do this..